# Encuesta MySQL y porcentaje

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, contador, sum, porcentaje

Tengo una tabla con una encuesta que marca respuestas de selección del 1 al 5, quisiera que me diera el total de personas que encuestan y el número de respuestas.
Para sacar el número de personas que encuesta utilizo esta sentencia:

```
SELECT docente, COUNT(nombre) 
FROM encuestacan 
GROUP BY docente 
order by docente asc
```

y sin problema me lo da
para sumar las respuestas que son uno uso:

```
SELECT
  docente,
  SUM(p1) AS total_uno
FROM encuestacan
WHERE p1 = '1'
GROUP BY docente  
ORDER BY  docente ASC;
```

el problema es que necesito sacar la suma de las otras respuestas que son 2, 3, 4 y 5 y el total de quienes encuestan para poder generar porcentajes. No se si alguien pueda orientarme. Gracias.

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta y pon la estructura de tu tabla, y de ser posible añade un ejemplo con datos reales y el resultado esperado

Answer (score 0):

Da la sensación de que lo que te impide dar con la solución es que no sabes que puedes agrupar por más de un campo. Prueba así:

```
SELECT docente,p1,COUNT(*) n
  FROM encuestacan
  GROUP BY 1,2
  ORDER BY 1;
```

Obtendrás, por cada docente, cuántas respuestas ha obtenido de cada tipo.